# Hex To Double Converting in C

Tags: c

I am trying to convert hex value to double value and I am using below codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

double HexToDoubleConverter(uint8_t *hexArray);
uint8_t dummyArray[10] = {0xb2 , 0x9c,  0x9b, 0x6e, 0xcd,  0x8f, 0x44,  0x40}; 

int main()
{
    printf("convertedValue : %f",HexToDoubleConverter((uint8_t *)&dummyArray) );

    return 0;
}


double HexToDoubleConverter(uint8_t *hexArray)
{
   uint64_t convertedValue = 0;
   uint8_t j;
   for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
  {
   convertedValue += ((char*)&hexArray)[j]; 
  }  

  return (*((double*)&convertedValue));
}
```

And also I tried like this:

```
   for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
  {
   convertedValue |= (hexArray[j] << (8 * j)); 
  }
```

But I get :`convertedValue : 0.000000` But I expected 41.123456789

How can I solve this where is my mistake ?

Comment: `convertedValue += ((char*)&hexArray)[j];` doesn't make any sens. Explain what you're trying to achieve here. What do you `convertedValue` expect to contain after  the for loop?

Comment: `convertedValue |= (hexArray[j] << (8 * j));` is almost correct, but you need `convertedValue |= ((uint64_t)hexArray[j] << (8 * j));` because `hexArray[j]` is implicitely converted to `int` before the shift, but you need it to be a `unint64_t`. But anyway, you should use  `memcpy` as suggested in the answer below.

Comment: Thank you for your response,  ((uint64_t)hexArray[j] << (8 * j)); works for me

Comment: `(*((double*)&convertedValue))` undefined behaviour

Comment: Okey, I ignored (*((double*)&convertedValue))  and I am using memcpy now. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This array contains the byte representation of the double number. You need to simply copy it into the double variable.

```
uint8_t dummyArray[10] = {0xb2 , 0x9c,  0x9b, 0x6e, 0xcd,  0x8f, 0x44,  0x40}; 

int main()
{
    double x;

    memcpy(&x,dummyArray, sizeof(x));
    printf("convertedValue : %f\n",x );

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/dP5nnWbb5

Do not worry about 'memcpy' call. This function is well known to the compiler and most of the compilers will replace it with simple assembly instructions

Comment: Thank you for another method, memcpy is faster than for loop ?

Comment: @hobik memcpy is certainly faster.

Comment: On most implementations yes as it will not call memcpy https://godbolt.org/z/M5T7bhbPo

Comment: Thank you very much, I put memcpy instead of" for loop"